# How to merge two files of different lines and column and output matching lines with colums?

Tags: text-processing, join

I have **file1** (sample):

```
60108903374
60172485121
60108919381
60174213128
60108919951
60108919970
601112020106
601112020107
601112020108
601112020113
601112020114
60175472940
```

And **file2**:

```
60179970001,A
60172681920,A
60174202041,A
60172514180,A
60174314679,A
60174325306,A
60175472940,A
60174213128,A
60175328984,A
60175349857,A
60172796759,A
60172798922,A
60179195129,A
60172485121,B
60173483126,A
60172683175,A
60174521828,A
60142536314,B
60175347909,B
60175183031,B
```

I want to merge `file1` and `file2` with output matching based on the first column as well as shows the second column from `file2`.

**Desired output**:

```
60172485121,B
60174213128,A
```

`file1` has ~80k lines and `file2` has 500k lines.

Tried using:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2 file1 file2
```

Comment: It is not important bu I think `60175472940,A` is missing in the "desired output"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
join -t, <(sort file1) <(sort -t, file2)
```

The above does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NF==1 {a[$1]++}; 
         NF>=2 && a[$1]' file1 file2
```

- if we have just one field, save it
- if we have more and the first field is saved, print it

output obtained:

```
60175472940,A
60174213128,A
60172485121,B
```